# DataGridView image just displays "System.Drawing.Bitmap"

Tags: .net, vb.net, image, datagridview

I am trying to load a picture into a DataGridView, but all the cell displays is "System Drawn Bitmap" can you help?

```
    DataGridPhoto.Columns.Clear()
    DataGridPhoto.Columns.Add("Name", "Name")
    DataGridPhoto.Columns.Add("Form", "Form")
    DataGridPhoto.Columns.Add("Admision", "Addmision")
    DataGridPhoto.Columns.Add("Photo", "Photo")

    DataGridPhoto.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells
    DataGridPhoto.Columns(0).DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True
    DataGridPhoto.Columns(1).DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True
    DataGridPhoto.Columns(2).DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True
    DataGridPhoto.Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True
    DataGridPhoto.Columns(0).Width = 150
    DataGridPhoto.Columns(1).Width = 50
    DataGridPhoto.Columns(2).Width = 50
    DataGridPhoto.Columns(3).Width = 100

    butPrint.Enabled = True
    For nLoop = 1 To NoOfLabels
        Dim n As Integer = DataGridPhoto.Rows.Add()
        DataGridPhoto.Rows(n).Cells("Name").Value = PrnStudentDetails(nLoop, 1) + " " + PrnStudentDetails(nLoop, 2)

        DataGridPhoto.Rows(n).Cells("Form").Value = PrnStudentDetails(nLoop, 3)
        DataGridPhoto.Rows(n).Cells("Admision").Value = PrnStudentDetails(nLoop, 4)
        Dim cPictureFilename As String
        cPictureFilename = AppPath & "\Photographs\" & PrnStudentDetails(nLoop, 4) & ".jpg"
        If File.Exists(cPictureFilename) Then
            DataGridPhoto.Rows(n).Cells("Photo").Value = Image.FromFile(cPictureFilename)
        End If

    Next
```

I'm guessing I have to tell the cell it's a picture, but can't find how to do this.

Regards
Graham

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several different types of DGV columns (`DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`, `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` etc) .  Your code is adding the default  `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` which will not be able to display an image.

```
Dim dc As New DataGridViewImageColumn() With {.HeaderText = "Photo", .Name = "Photo"}
dgv2.Columns.Add(dc)

dgv2.Rows.Add(1)
dgv2.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value = Image.FromFile("C:\Temp\London.jpg")
```

Or:

```
dgv2.Columns.Add(New DataGridViewImageColumn() With {.HeaderText = "Photo",
                                                     .Name = "Photo"})
...
```

You may also want to set the `ImageLayout` property to automatically resized each/all the images.  I am not sure why you clear the columns unless it is to define a completely different column layout.  To remove any old data you could just clear the rows.

Comment: I knew I had to define the column as a picture column, but everything I tried just failed and didn't work. Thanks so much for your help. I clear the columns because that's the way I was showed how to do the data grid, I clear columns and just redo the grid from scratch. Never thought to just delete the rows!